# Get position in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I use ListView to show several items.
My row.xml as below:

```
<TextView android:text="text"
android:id="@+id/tvViewRow"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
<Button android:text="Click me!"
android:id="@+id/BtnToClick"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="myClick">
</Button>
```

And I define myClick in Activity as below:

```
public void myClick (View v) {
LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
//How to get the position
}
```

How to know the position which buttom be clicked?
The position mean same as the method onListItemClick's.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked before, please look up questions before posting.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try

```
public void DetailClick(View v) {
ListView lv = getListView();
int position = lv.getPositionForView(v);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that! why is that information so hidden?

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this.

Step 1: In your custom adapter

```
@Override
public view getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
.......//Perform your logic
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.BtnToClick).setTag(position);
    return convertView;
}
```

Step 2: In onclick listener

```
 public void myClick (View v) {
     LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
     position=(Integer) v.getTag();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the position in the onListItemClick is same as the position of the item clicked in the list.

Comment: I mean how to get the position in myClick method

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a button in each row of a `ListView`, and you want to know which row received the button click. How are you doing an `setOnClickListener()` on the button? The reason I ask this is - if you are setting the `OnClickListener` for each button, you already know the position of that button.

Comment: I have set onClick="myClick" in xml.

Comment: and define a new method of myClick

Answer (score 1):

You should also read the documentation for [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) and even look through the available methods and their sample code.

**Know your documentation.**